# Select distinct of multiple columns from prestodb

Tags: sql, distinct, presto, trino

I am trying to do similar of
`SELECT DISTINCT tid, open_dt from table_name` in `prestodb` where these values are repeated in multiple rows with other column values changing. But, this doesn't seem to work. I have tried using
`SELECT DISTINCT ROW(tid, open_dt) from table_name`, but this gives the results more like in json sort of format with one column having values as `{field0='tid123', field1='2020-12-01'}`.
I want to use the query as an inner query in a join. Is there a way to do it and get the results like a normal table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by on all required columns:

```sql
SELECT tid, open_dt 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY tid, open_dt
```

Comment: It is a huge table with billions of rows. Doesn't group by gonna be too much resource intensive?

Comment: @Jihjohn I doubt that it will differ from any other approach which you can use to find all distinct pairs. Based on query plans it looks like your `row` approach without extra projection.

Comment: I have tested it out. Seems fast enough. Thank you